# How to view files that have read permission only in my present working directory?

Tags: linux, shell-script

This question seems an easy one for anyone who knows find command. But let's assume that find command doesn't work on my system. How can I view the files based on their permissions without using "find" command?

Comment: any specific reason for not using `find` ?

Comment: did any of us answer helped you or not ?

Comment: Yes, It really helped me a lot.

Comment: No, I am new to this site

Answer (score 4):

Without `find`, you still have a shell (which can expand wildcards) and can loop over the contents of the directory checking first if each is a file, then if it is not writable, and then if it is not executable and then if it is readable.

Someone is likely to write a script to demonstrate, but it helps to start by reading the documentation, e.g., [POSIX test](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html).

By the way, the use of "**only**" in the question's title would exclude results where the file is either writable or executable.  In [POSIX `find`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html), you can express it like this:

```
find . -type f \! \( -perm -u=w -o -perm -u=x -o -perm -g=w -o -perm -g=x -o -perm -o=w -o -perm -o=x \)
```

[GNU `find`](http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Mode-Bits) provides extensions which allow more compact expressions:

```
find . -type f \! -perm /u=wx,g=wx,o=wx
```

The `test` utility (more often used as `[` and `]`) provides simpler tests than `find`, e.g.,

```
for name in *; do [ -f "$name" -a -r "$name" -a ! -w "$name" -a ! -x "$name" ] && ls -l "$name"; done
```

However, its permissions are only for the *user*, not *group* or *other*.  To exclude files based on those, you can use `ls`, e.g.,

```
for name in *; do [ -f "$name" ] && case "$(ls -l "$name")" in -r--r--r--*) echo "$name";; esac; done
```

or (if you want to allow executable files)

```
for name in *; do [ -f "$name" ] && case "$(ls -l "$name")" in -r-?r-?r-*) echo "$name";; esac; done
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use,

```
# for file in /your/path/*; do [ -r "$file" ] && [ -f "$file" ] && printf '%s\n' "$file"; done
```

- `-r` stands for, file exists and read permission is granted.

---

To find readable files regardless of owner, group or others, you can check the `r` flag in the file permission column of ls.

```
ls -l | awk '$1 ~ /r/'
```

Comment: Not bad, but you can simplify it *and* increase robustness: `for f in /your/path/*; do [ -r "$f" ] && [ -f "$f ] && printf '%s\n' "$f"; done`.  Also see [Why is printf better than echo?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/135943) and [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/135943)

Comment: @Wildcard why to use `[ -f $f ]` ? because `-r` itself checks for file existence and readable

Comment: `-f` checks that a file is a regular file.  `-r` checks for readability.  `[ -r somedirectory ]` will return true.  Perhaps the Original Poster wanted to include readable directories in his results list, but when you're new to a language it's easier to remove the flags (options) you don't need than to add options you don't know, so I thought it better to assume he wanted regular files only.  (Also, it's `[ -f "$f" ]`, not `[ -f $f ]`.)  ;)

Comment: @Wildcard Ohh, thanks, edited my answer as per your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `ls -l` in conjunction with `grep`:

```
ls -l | grep -e "-r[w-][x-][r-][w-][x-][r-][w-][x-]"
```

This would show you only files that you have read permission to. If you add `[-d]` instead of the dash at the beginning of the pattern, you would get also directories.

Comment: **grep -e "-r[rwx-]{8}"** is probably a bit nicer to read

Comment: @Michael nicer to read yes, however I specifically chose the long version because it is more educational. Also, it is easier adapted to specific needs (by replacing a certain brace with the respective letter to be queried for).

Answer (score 1):

Along the lines of what Thawn said above,
aiming for the *simplest solution* as a priority
(and assuming you can use ls, since you can't use `find`;

**you could do `ls -l | grep ^.r\-\-`** to find exactly what you asked for,
"files that have read permission only..."

For example

```
touch testfile.txt
chmod 0400 testfile.txt
ls -l | grep ^.r\-\-
```

outputs

```
`-r--------   1 youruser  yourgroup     0  6 Jun 11:20 testfile.txt'
```

Comment: Obviously it might be a lot more "fun" to an experienced user to loop over the directory with scripts like many have already written here

Answer (score 0):

With `zsh`:

```
view ./*(.^f-444)
```

or:

```
view ./*(.r,.A,.R)
```

Would view the non-hidden regular files that have at least one of the read permission bits set. Equivalent of:

```
find . ! -name . -prune ! -name '.*' -type f \(
  -perm -001 -o -perm -010 -o -perm -100 \)
```

or with GNU `find`:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 ! -name '.*' -type f -perm /444
```

While:

```
view ./*(.e:'[ -r $REPLY ]':)
```

would view the non-hidden regular files that *you* have permission to read. Equivalent of:

```
find . ! -name . -prune ! -name '.*' -type f -exec test -r {} \; -print
```

Or with GNU `find`:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 ! -name '.*' -type f -readable
```

And:

```
view ./*(.f-7333^f-444)
```

To view non-hidden regular files where only read permission bits (at least one) are set.

Equivalent of GNU `find`'s:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 ! -name '.*' -perms /444 ! -perms /7333
```